# Nginx access.log showing different URL than requested

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Our server has a nginx reverse-proxy on port 80 forwarding the requests to apache on port 8081. It is working well, except for a while we have some requests that are automatically redirected to the website homepage.

For example if we try to access **http://www.website.com/product1** 
We get redirected to **http://www.website.com**

Apache access log shows "GET / HTTP/1.0"

Nginx access log shows "GET / HTTP/1.0"

How is it possible that the requested URI "/product1" becomes "/" in nginx access log ?